# Stackdriver vs ELK for app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, google-cloud-platform

Im a little confused about this because the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/logging) say I can use stackdriver for "Request logs and application logs for App Engine applications" so does that mean like web requests? Does that mean like millions of web requests?

Stackdriver's pricing is per resource so does that mean I can log all of my web servers web request logs (which would be HUGE) for no extra cost (meaning I would not be charged by the volume of storage the logs use)?

Does stackdriver use GCP cloud storage as a backend and do I have to pay for the storage? It just looks like I can get hundreds of gigabytes of log aggregation for virtually no money just want to make sure Im understanding this.

I bring up ELK because elastic just partnered with google so it must not do everything elasticsearch does (for almost no money) otherwise it would be a competitor?

Comment: That document you  linked to dates back to November 2014, so I'm not certain it is still relevant.

Comment: this the problem with GCP right now, docs are all over the place. Do you mean not relevant as in it doesn't to web requests, like its scope has been limited? Or is that a super premo feature? I just want to know if Im charged for storing the millions of request logs I'd like to run through it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things definitely seem to be moving quickly at Google's cloud division and documentation does seem to suffer a bit.

Having said that, the document you linked to also details the limitations -

> The request and application logs for your app are collected by a Cloud
>   Logging agent and are kept for a maximum of 90 days, up to a maximum
>   size of 1GB. If you want to store your logs for a longer period or
>   store a larger size than 1GB, you can export your logs to Cloud
>   Storage. You can also export your logs to BigQuery and Pub/Sub for
>   further processing.

It should work out of the box for small to medium sized projects. The built in log viewer is also pretty basic.

From your description, it sounds like you may have specific needs, so you should not assume this will be free. You should factor in costs for Cloud Storage for the logs you want to retain and BigQuery depending on your needs to crunch the logs.

Comment: This was a kind of lazy question which I apologize for. I found a doc on their pricing as well. It seems even at the premo level its only 10Gbs per resource with a 30 day retention.

Comment: No need to apologize :) I get lost in the docs pretty regularly and appreciate an extra pair of eyes from time to time!